# perl linux command not working

Tags: linux, perl

```
cat t.incopt.02.20110221 | awk -F, '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

got unque records

but if i inserted into perl,

```
@FETCH_REQ_DETAILS = `cat t.incopt.02.20110221 | awk -F\, '{print $1}' \| sort \| uniq`;
```

if i print the above array vari, i getting entire file content,  i guess the linux command not working correctly when i use inside perl,

Comment: why \ before pipes? (not all of them even)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to enclose the command in back tick and escape only the $

```
@FETCH_REQ_DETAILS = `cat t.incopt.02.20110221 | awk -F, '{print \$1}' | sort | uniq;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

my $cmd='cat t.incopt.02.20110221 | awk -F, \'{print $1}\' | sort | uniq';

@FETCH_REQ_DETAILS = `$cmd`;